# Group students by grade and having max age

Tags: java

Please help to improve my Java 7 code. I would like a best code logic to achieve this.

```
package main.java;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String grade;
    private int age;

    public Student(int id, String grade, int age){
        this.id = id;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    // group student by grade and having max of age
    public static List<Student> getStudentsWithMaxAgeOfEachGrade(List<Student> students){
        ArrayList<Student> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Student s : students){
            boolean found = false;
            for(Student rs : result){
                if(rs.getGrade().equals(s.getGrade()) && rs.getAge() < s.getAge()){
                    found = true;
                    result.remove(rs);
                    result.add(s);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found == false){
                result.add(s);
            }
        }

        return result;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        Student s1 = new Student(1, "a", 32);
        Student s2 = new Student(2, "a", 34);
        Student s3 = new Student(3, "b", 23);

        students.add(s1);
        students.add(s2);
        students.add(s3);

        List<Student> result = getStudentsWithMaxAgeOfEachGrade(students);

        for(Student s : result){
            System.out.println(s.getGrade() + ":" + s.getAge());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the aim of your assignment? Was it implementing the sort algorithm?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1):

in your code, you have getter and setter for id. But those methods are not used. I have posted a similar question before. And multiple people told me "we shouldn't have dead code."

Since you want to return List of Student, I would construct the HashMap to map from string(grade) to Student instead of string to integer (where you will lose the student id).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Student> getStudentsWithMaxAgeOfEachGrade(final List<Student> students) {
    if (students.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    // Make a copy of input, because we don't want to modify it
    List<Student> copy = new ArrayList<>(students);

    // Sort by age (desc)
    Collections.sort(copy, new Comparator<Student>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o2.getAge(), o1.getAge());
        }
    });

    List<Student> result = new ArrayList<>();

    // First element is always included in the result
    result.add(copy.get(0));
    // Start with the second element (index 1), we can find a maximum of 6 different grades (a-f)
    for (int i = 1; i < copy.size() && result.size() <= 6; i++) {
        Student s = copy.get(i);
        boolean hasGrade = false;
        for (Student rs : result) {
            // Do our result already have this grade?
            if (rs.getGrade().equals(s.getGrade())) {
                hasGrade = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!hasGrade) {
            result.add(s);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Test data:

```
id, grade, age
1, "a", 32
2, "a", 34
3, "b", 23
4, "d", 22
5, "c", 26
6, "f", 20
7, "f", 19
8, "e", 27
9, "b", 26
```

Result:

```
yours:
a:34
d:22
c:26
f:20
f:19 <-- You have a bug?! (I have not resolved this)
e:27
b:26

mine:
a:34
e:27
c:26
b:26
d:22
f:20
```

Edit: If you want JDK 1.8 :)

```
public static List<Student> getStudentsWithMaxAgeOfEachGrade(final List<Student> students) {
    if (students.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    // Make a copy of input, because we don't want to modify it
    List<Student> copy = new ArrayList<>(students);

    // Sort by age (desc)
    copy.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getAge).reversed());

    List<Student> result = new ArrayList<>();

    // First element is always included in the result
    result.add(copy.get(0));
    // Start with the second element (index 1), we can find a maximum of 6 different grades (a-f)
    for (int i = 1; i < copy.size() && result.size() <= 6; i++) {
        Student s = copy.get(i);
        if (result.stream().map(Student::getGrade).noneMatch(s.getGrade()::equals)) {
            result.add(s);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative implementation without reviewing the code provided by the author. On Code Review, all answers should contain a review.

Comment: "You have a bug" is the only part of this answer that is considered a code review. Please explain that part more.

Comment: I think his bug is that he goes through each element in the result and then if the student's age is less than rs->age, then found will be stay at false and then a duplicate grade will be added to result

Answer (score 0):

A completely different solution in comparison to my first solution
Use a Map as a return type:
(But keep in mind, that you will lose information about student in this version. So no information about id anymore)

```
public static Map<String, Integer> getStudentsWithMaxAgeOfEachGrade(final List<Student> students) {
    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Student s : students) {
        Integer value = result.get(s.getGrade());
        if (value == null || value < s.getAge()) {
            result.put(s.getGrade(), s.getAge());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Edit: If you want JDK 1.8 :)

```
public static Map<String, Integer> getStudentsWithMaxAgeOfEachGrade(final List<Student> students) {
    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    students.forEach((s) -> {
        result.merge(s.getGrade(), s.getAge(), (oldValue, newValue) -> {
            return oldValue == null || oldValue < newValue ? newValue : oldValue;
        });
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You could return `new ArrayList(result.valueSet())` to comply with the original Method signature...

Comment: Thanks, but we need a return type as list not map.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle valueSet() is undefined of object result, do you have other way?

Comment: @RadyArchuleta this is the kind of inconsistency in the Java API that always confuses me: the `Map` interface has the `keySet()` method to get the keys but the `values()` method (without *set*) to get the values...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle that's because the keys can only be there once, but values can exist multiple times. So I can have a,b,c,d,e,f as keys and 
34,27,26,26,22,20 as values

Comment: Hi all, I got the best solution 
private static List<Student> getList(List<Student> students) {
        Map<Character, Student> stMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Student student : students) {
            char grade = student.getGrade();
            if (stMap.containsKey(grade) && stMap.get(grade).getAge() < student.getAge()) {
                stMap.put(grade, student);
            } else if (!stMap.containsKey(grade)) {
                stMap.put(grade, student);
            }
        }

        return new ArrayList<>(stMap.values());
    }